# Multiple show/hide buttons with button text change on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a wordpress page with several buttons, that show/hide a certain div, also the button text changes from "more info" to "less info" according to button click.

This is my code so far, but as i have multiple buttons, of course each time i click on one, the code is executed for all hidden divs and button texts.

What has the code to be like, that it only affects the one button actually clicked / hidden div at a time?

Heres the HTML:

```
<a class="clicker reveal" style="background-color: #81d742; border: 0px; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none;">MORE INFOS</a>
```

and JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.noConflict();

    // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".slider").hide();

        jQuery('.reveal').click(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).text() === 'MORE INFOS') {
                jQuery(this).text('LESS INFOS');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).text('MORE INFOS');
            }
        });

        jQuery(".clicker").click(function(){
            jQuery(".slider").slideToggle("slow");

            jQuery.each(masterslider_instances, function(i, slider) {
                slider.api.update();
                slider.api.__resize(true);
                jQuery.each(slider.controls, function( index, control ) {
                    if (control.realignThumbs) control.realignThumbs();
                });

                jQuery.each(masterslider_instances, function(a,b){
                    b.api.update(true);
                });
            });  

        });
    });
</script>
```

and the targeted div:

```
<div class="slider>Some content</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use id selector instead of class

Comment: Please paste your div which is respective to this button. You should make some reference between the button and div to make it work

Comment: pasted div. I know that there needs to be a reference to make it work, but thats exactly my problem, i dont know how to code that... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

I am informed that the button is in a div, the update reflects that small change:

From:

```
var tgt = $(this).next('.slider');
```

To:

```
var tgt = $(this).parent().next('.slider');
```

The following demo uses the class methods. Details are provided within the source in the comments.

#### SNIPPET

```js
/*
Removed a chunk of meaningless code 
since there's no way of using it 
because the plugin isn't 
provided (I'm assuming).
*/

$(function() {

  /*
  Combined both the `more/less` and 
  `slideToggle()` features under one 
  class(`.reveal`) and one click event.
  */
  $('.reveal').on('click', function(e) {
    /*
    Prevent anchor from default behavior 
    of jumping to a location.
    */
    e.preventDefault();
    /*
    See if `.reveal` has class `.more`
    */
    var more = $(this).hasClass('more');
    /*
    `.tgt` is the next `.slider` after 
    `this`(clicked `a.reveal`).
    */
    var tgt = $(this).parent().next('.slider');
    /*
    Toggle `.reveal`'s state between `.more` and 
    `.less` classes. (See CSS)
    */
    if (more) {
      $(this).removeClass('more').addClass('less');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('less').addClass('more');
    }
    /*
    `slideToggle()` only the `div.slider` that 
    follows `this` (clicked `a.reveal`)
    */
    tgt.slideToggle('slow');
  });

});
```

```css
.reveal {
  display: block;
}
.reveal.more:before {
  content: 'MORE INFO';
}
.reveal.less:before {
  content: 'LESS INFO';
}
.slider {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<a class="reveal more" href="" style="background-color: #81d742; border: 0px; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none;"></a>
</div>
<div class="slider">Some content</div>

<div>
<a class="reveal more" href="" style="background-color: #81d742; border: 0px; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none;"></a>
</div>
<div class="slider">Some content</div>

<div>
<a class="reveal more" href="" style="background-color: #81d742; border: 0px; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none;"></a>
</div>
<div class="slider">Some content</div>
```

Comment: that looks great, thanks! however, ive tried to incorporate my other stuff and its not working, did i place it in the wrong spot or did i kill the syntax?

https://jsfiddle.net/7jo1x6rc/

Comment: That extra code needs a plugin, do you recall any separate file named similar to this?: `jquery.slider.js` or `jquery.slider.min.js`

Comment: @Mella, you must have a WordPress site, MasterSlider is a free WP plugin, there's a Pro and jQuery paid versions as well. If you're using the free version, then that extra code is server-side/WP dependent. Go [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider/?ref=averta) to get info to download and install.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, i am using masterslider in wp site. I need this code executed, because without the slides look garbled due to the hide/Show. Your solution is working, but not in my case, because ive forgot to mention that the button is nested in another div, so its like

Comment: That would be a small modification, using `.closest` or  `.parent()` instead of `.next()`

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, i am using masterslider in wp site. I need this code executed, because without the slides look garbled due to the hide/Show. Your solution is working, but not in my case, because ive forgot to mention that the button is nested in another div, so its like <div outer><div inner>button</div><div class=Slider>content</div></div>

Comment: I corrected your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/e71Lvavy/1/) and commented out that MasterSlider. Once you get that code on your site, just remove all of the comments just to be safe `/* all of this */` `//and all of this`

Comment: thanks so much, but i cant get it to work. if i nest the button like in my last comment it does work (it didnt before your parent() change), but when i insert it in my page its not working, even with MasterSlider code commented out. I copied the relevant div in the fiddle to reproduce the error. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/e71Lvavy/7/ perhaps that helps...

Comment: note: the button text toggle is working in wp, but not in the first button on the fiddle

Comment: I found it! due to my div structure its parent_S_() instead of parent() and for the masterslide code part i forgot to close it properly...
Thanks a lot for your help, i wouldnt have managed without you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 jQuery('.reveal').each(function(idx,item) {
  jQuery(item).click(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).text() === 'MORE INFOS') {
     jQuery(this).text('LESS INFOS');
    }
    else {
      jQuery(this).text('MORE INFOS');
    }

  });
});
```

Here is working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9kf38x/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a reference between the anchor and div by using data attribute.

```
<a class="clicker reveal" data-target="slider-1" style="background-color: #81d742; border: 0px; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none;">MORE INFOS</a>

<div class="slider slider-1">Some content</div>
```

Now, you can do the following-

```
jQuery('.clicker').click(function() {
  var targetDiv = jQuery('.' + jQuery(this).attr('data-target'))
  if (jQuery(this).text() === 'MORE INFOS') {
    jQuery(this).text('LESS INFOS');
    targetDiv.slideDown('slow');
  } else {
    jQuery(this).text('MORE INFOS');
    targetDiv.slideUp('slow');
  }

  // do the rest of your stuff here
});
```